# Login page doesn't get fully loaded using selenium webdriver and PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to access the WSJ login page, using the Python selenium webdriver and PhantomJS.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://id.wsj.com/access/pages/wsj/us/login_standalone.html")
driver.save_screenshot('login.png')
```

For some reason, it never gets fully loaded as I see on the screenshot: it has no CSS and probably no Javascript loaded. This is probably why my login does not work.

I have no idea how to debug this, or how to make sure the other content gets loaded. When I use this with the Firefox webdriver, it looks all good and I can login.

Any ideas? Using selenium 2.35, phantomjs 1.9.1

Comment: Try waiting for an element that you care about, and then take a screenshot.

Comment: Lookup selenium docs for implicit and explicit waits - http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits

Comment: this works perfectly over here. nothing is wrong with your code, its pretty straight forward. what does your screenshot look like?

Comment: Thank you both. The issue probably is because of SSL certificate issues. This occurs at my company, not at home I found out now. Will probably have to make it ignore SSL-certificate errors.. @TehTris: the screen looks like bare-bones HTML with no markup at all, just the login boxes. However I can't login, probably because Javascript was not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true'])
```

Give credit to:
ashemedai commented on 9 Aug 2013
at: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/233